# How to compare two approximation algorithms

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, approximation

We say that "An algorithm is a $\beta$-approximation to problem $X$, if for any instance of problem $X$, the solution returned by this algorithm is within a factor $\beta$ of the optimal solution".

Now assume that we have a $\log(N)$-approximation algorithm (called it Alg 1) for problem $X$ where $N$ is the size of problem $X$. Further assume there is one other algorithm (called it Alg 2) for problem $X$, but for that algorithm we could find an instance of problem $X$ with size $N$ such that the solution returned by Alg 2 is $N/2$ times of the optimal solution.

What is a correct way of saying this statement that clearly shows that Alg 1 is much more better than Alg 2? I was thinking about the following one:

"Alg 2 provides a $\beta$-approximation to problem $X$ where $\beta \geq N/2$."

Is this correct? Any better suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I would write something like this: whereas Alg 1 is a $\log(N)$-approximation algorithms, there are instances on which the approximation ratio of Alg 2 is only $N/2$. So Alg 1 is much better (in the worst case) than Alg 2.

Comment: One question: saying Alg 1 is "much better" is okay for a paper? Or you think these relative terms are not exact?

Comment: Not everything you write in a paper has to be exact – only the mathematical parts. "Much better" is as good a phrase as any.